# Insert multiple rows where not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why is `not exists` for the insert into `#productType` table resulting in duplicates? Seems like it should work and I see a ton of SO answers using the same solution but it simply doesn't work. The expected result is to have only a single row inserted into the `#productType` table.

All of my code is running under a transaction using DbUp, so I can't use the `merge` statement either. Any ideas on how to modify this?

```
use master

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#product') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    drop table #product;
END
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#productType') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    alter table #productType drop constraint [PK_ProductType];
    drop table #productType;
END
GO

create table #productType (
    [ProductTypeId] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ProductTypeId] ASC
    )
);

create table #product (
    [NewProductId] int NOT NULL,
    [TypeName] varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    [CartDisplayName] varchar(1000) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #product ([NewProductId], [TypeName], [CartDisplayName])
VALUES
(1, 'MyProduct', '5" x 7" MyProduct'),
(2, 'MyProduct', '8" x 8" MyProduct'),
(3, 'MyProduct', '8" x 10" MyProduct'),
(4, 'MyProduct', '11" x 14" MyProduct'),
(5, 'MyProduct', '12" x 12" MyProduct'),
(6, 'MyProduct', '12" x 18" MyProduct'),
(7, 'MyProduct', '16" x 20" MyProduct'),
(8, 'MyProduct', '8" x 24" MyProduct'),
(9, 'MyProduct', '16" x 16" MyProduct'),
(10, 'MyProduct', '10" x 20" MyProduct'),
(11, 'MyProduct', '18" x 24" MyProduct'),
(12, 'MyProduct', '15" x 30" MyProduct'),
(13, 'MyProduct', '20" x 24" MyProduct'),
(14, 'MyProduct', '20" x 30" MyProduct'),
(15, 'MyProduct', '20" x 40" MyProduct'),
(16, 'MyProduct', '24" x 24" MyProduct'),
(17, 'MyProduct', '24" x 36" MyProduct'),
(18, 'MyProduct', '30" x 40" MyProduct')

insert into #productType ([Name])
select [TypeName] from #product p
where not exists (SELECT 1 FROM #productType cpt
 WHERE cpt.[Name] = p.TypeName)

select * from #productType
```

[image: results]

Comment: Nothing exists in `#productType` when you run your `insert into` so the condition will be true. It doesn't loop to check the condition after each row is inserted. If you really are inserting into an empty table, I would just do `insert into #productType ([Name]) select DISTINCT [TypeName] from #product p1` (I added the `DISTINCT` and removed your `WHERE` condition completely).

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this, as the "not exists" is checked against the producttype state that it was at before this statement ran. so you would have to loop and insert 1 at a time. Best approach would just to use the distinct keyword.

You query will only ever work on tables which contain data.

Change your query to this:

```
insert into #productType ([Name])
select DISTINCT [TypeName] 
from #product p
where not exists (
    SELECT *
    FROM #productType cpt
    WHERE cpt.[Name] = p.TypeName)
```